# Restrict Author to use only one category and not more than 3 tag

Tags: php, wordpress

I am currently developing a community website using WordPress buddypress. Is there any way to restrict author or buddypress members who can use only one category and maximum 3 tag during they submit a post in the blog section. If they use more than one category the and more than 3 tag for the post then it cannot be publish and a error message show up.

My bellow code only show a message when select more than one category. But Now I need help for the tag section

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
$("#category-tabs li.hide-if-no-js").hide(); //Hides Most Used tab
$("#category-all input:checkbox").change(function () {
    var max = 1; // Max allowed cats
    var count = $("#category-all input:checked").length; //counts selected cats
    if (count > max) {
        $(this).prop("checked", "");
        alert('You are only allowed to select ' + max + ' categories.'); //alert message when user tries to select a third cat
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: Yes, what have you tried so far?

Comment: @ɴᴀᴛʜ I have update my question please take a look what I am doing wrong its not working.

Comment: My code works but I need help for the tag section